# Excel - Scheduling persons in the correct cell of working hours

Tags: excel, scheduling, rostering

I'm head of a group of students organising events. In the picture you see 3 tables:

- First the event with the persons and their hours they will do their job on the event
- Secondly the amount of persons I have for that specific hour interval.
- And thirdly (what my question is about), I would like to see in a way that the people that I selected to work from 16-18 will show in one string (Person 1, Person 3) in the cell I2

I can't figure out in which order I would be using the formulas of Excel to execute this.

Thanks in advance

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSvXx.png)

Comment: This is only possible with native formulas, if you have a subscription to Office 365 Excel, which introduced TEXTJOIN(), otherwise it will need to be a long complicated nested IF, which if you only have 3 is not too bad, but I assume there will be a lot more than three.  Or you can use VBA.

Comment: We are 10, but if you can show an example of all the IF statements to use for the 3 persons, I would be able to continue with that example @ScottCraner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a subscritption to Office 365 Excel then something like this array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF($B2:$D2=I1,$B$1:$D$1,""))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

---

***IF you do not have a subscription to Office 365 Excel***

Then put this code in a module attached to the workbook and use the formula as described above:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

---

Linked IF():

```
=LEFT(IF($B2=I1,$B$1 & ",","") & IF($C2=I1,$C$1 & ",","") & IF($D2=I1,$D$1 & ",",""),LEN(IF($B2=I1,$B$1 & ",","") & IF($C2=I1,$C$1 & ",","") & IF($D2=I1,$D$1 & ",",""))-1)
```

Comment: The usage of textjoin made it work, Office 16 has this formula too. I was unaware of the existence of this one. I thank you, this helped me a lot.